# jQuery Cycle with IF and ELSE statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if (!jQuery.browser.msie)
        {
            $('.banner').cycle({
                fx: 'fade',
                speed: 1000,
                timeout: 10000,
                random: 1
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.banner').cycle({
                fx: 'turnUp',
                speed: 1000,
                timeout: 10000,
                random: 1
            });
        }
    });
```

However the .banner does not cycle in IE. If I change the Fx to fade though it will work?? Any ideas why I can't have a different effect, the IF and ELSE is defo working, just seems to break when I have a different effect on the IE one.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of jquery and cycle are you using?  Also you should use `!jQuery.support.opacity` instead of checking the browser.

Comment: Hmm just checked another version of cycle plugin and now it works :/ not sure why this would effect the if and else statement though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't using the latest version of Cycle. Not sure why this would effect the IF and ELSE statement though :/

Answer (score 0):

The plugin version is the likely culprit here, upgrade that to resolve the issue.  Also, you can slim this down with a conditional statement, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.banner').cycle({
     fx: $.support.opacity ? 'fade' : 'turnUp',
     speed: 1000,
     timeout: 10000,
     random: 1
  });
});
```

This uses [`jQuery.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) to check for opacity support, using [feature detection rather than browser detection](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-browser-feature-detection/) (IE9 for example *does* support opacity)...if at all possible, this is the best way to go.